# Why I get this output in this case?

Tags: python, python-3.x, struct, byte, pack

Given the following code:

```
import struct
field_size_4_bytes = 1234
field_size_2_bytes = 2
field_size_16_bytes = bytes("1234567812345678", 'utf-8')
res = struct.pack('<lh16s', field_size_4_bytes , field_size_2_bytes , field_size_16_bytes )
print(res)
```

Why I get this output:

```
b'\xd2\x04\x00\x00\x02\x001234567812345678'
```

1. Why, for example, I get the number "1234567812345678" as is, but "1234" is presented as `\xd2\x04\x00\x00`. And how `\xd2\x04\x00\x00` is related to `1234`?
2. Why before `001234567812345678` I see only one `\x`, but before the others I see some `\x`.
3. How is the meaning of 4 bytes, 8 bytes, and 16 bytes reflected in the output?

Comment: I think that `'\xd2\x04\x00\x00` is related to `field_size_4_bytes = 1234` but `0xd2` is `210` in decimal so i dont see how is rlated to the number 1234

Comment: In your code, 1234567812345678 is **not a number**, it is a string(!). That is the primary difference. The number 1234 encode into 4 bytes is 0xd20400 (little endian), the number 2 encoded into 2 bytes is 0x0200 (little endian), those are all "unprintable" bytes, while a string - generally - consists of printable bytes.